# X Ray Transparency keeps reseting

Tags: interface, add-on, settings

I like more visible x ray, but it just keeps reseting to 0.5 for no reason.

I got few addons installed but I don't think that is the case... maybe not?

Need help, maybe there are some settings for it, or I will just try disabling addons.

[image: Overlay]

Comment: Have you saved a Start Up File with X-Ray set the way you want it?

Comment: @curious_1hey I posted answer, yes I had, but it did reset on same project during work, veryyyyyy annoying :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue after investigation.

First idea was to check info window, usually it shows commands executed in blender. Unfortunately it showed only my changes.

[image: Info Window]

So I tried going through different modes and check if opacity would change.
It did change when going to `Object mode` with Machine Tools addon, but not with manual mode selection.

To disable it, there is setting pannel in Addons -> MAchine tool.

Uncheck Toggle Xray (set to `False`)
[image: Addons]

Comment: Glad you found it yourself, because nobody here who hasn't got this addon would have found it. Your question only said you have "few addons installed", so none of us knew which.